# Scroll related issue in child ListView which is inside a Parent ListView in flutter app

Tags: flutter, listview, flutter-layout

Presently I am working on a grocery shop kind of app and using flutter as framework for the implementation of the same and am encountering a problem related to scroll.
In the gif in the link given below a nested ListView is there which is not letting me scroll upwards after I reach to it's top ListItem.
I need to tap and drag that yellow card in order to scroll upwards.

Gif's Link :- https://i.ibb.co/SXv9jxC/vege.gif

```
Center(
        child: Container(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
            child: StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
              
              stream: Firestore.instance.collection('productList').snapshots(),
              builder: (BuildContext context,
                  AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot> snapshot) {
                if (snapshot.hasError)
                  return new Text('Error: ${snapshot.error}');
                switch (snapshot.connectionState) {
                  case ConnectionState.waiting:
                    return new Text('Loading...');
                  default:
                    return ListView(
                      physics:ClampingScrollPhysics(),
                      children: [
                        Padding(
                          padding: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 18.0),
                          child: Container(
                            padding: EdgeInsets.only(right: 15,left:15,top:25),
                            child: ClipRRect(
                                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
                                child: Image.network(
                                    'some image link')),
                          ),
                        ),
                        SizedBox(
                          height: 165,
                          child: ListView(
                            physics:ClampingScrollPhysics(),
                            scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                            children: [
                              ListCategory(selected: true),
                              ListCategory(
                                name: "Fruits",
                                imageUrl:
                                    "https://www.pinclipart.com/picdir/big/20-206947_les-fruits-vegetables-grade-1-sketching-centre-funny.png",
                              ),
                              ListCategory(
                                name: "Assorted",
                                imageUrl:
                                    "https://www.pinclipart.com/picdir/big/38-384870_galatians-bowl-of-fruits-clip-art-png-download.png",
                              )
                            ],
                          ),
                        ),
                        Expanded(
                          child: Padding(
                            padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 8.0),
                            child: SizedBox(
                              height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.76,
                              child: new ListView(
                                physics:ClampingScrollPhysics(),
                                children: snapshot.data.documents
                                    .map((DocumentSnapshot document) {
                                  return new VegCard(
                                    name: document['name'],
                                    unit: document['unit'],
                                    cost: document['cost'],
                                    imageUrl: document['imageUrl'],
                                    leastCount: document['leastCount'],
                                    available: document['available'],
                                    tags: document['tags'],
                                  );
                                }).toList(),
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ],
                    );
                }
              },
            )),
      ),
```

Comment: try    physics: PageScrollPhysics(),

Comment: Tried it but it didn't help

Answer (score 0):

You have added ListView inside another ListView.
So, Inner ListView can't Scroll Outer ListView.

You can use ListView.builder() to create mixed List of Your Widget & Widget with firebase Data.

refer this [Example](https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/lists/mixed-list)

Comment: Aditya thank you for your prompt reply but I was not able to understand and apply that solution in my case .
Could you please help me to understand how to apply the same thing in my case?

Answer (score 0):

the last expanded widget should look like this

```
Expanded(
                      child: Padding(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 8.0),
                        child: SizedBox(
                          height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.76,
                          child: ListView.builder(
                       scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
                      itemCount: snapshot.data.documents.length,
                       itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                         DocumentSnapshot document=snapshot.data.documents[index];
                         return VegCard(
                                name: document['name'],
                                unit: document['unit'],
                                cost: document['cost'],
                                imageUrl: document['imageUrl'],
                                leastCount: document['leastCount'],
                                available: document['available'],
                                tags: document['tags'],
                         );
                       }),
                       })
```

This is how you use a ListView.builder....Let me know if that is working for you and I suggest you do the same with the above widget

Comment: No it didn't work in my case but thank you for prompt reply

Answer (score 0):

What you're trying to do is not achieved automatically by flutter on it's own. You need to tell it that when the inner listview reaches it's top you want to scroll the outer listview.
You need to use scroll controllers for both the lists.

Comment: Can you give an example?